# Why does this regex not exclude hyphens or brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex is the bane of my existence. I've done plenty tutorials, but the rules never stick, and when I look them up they seem to conflict. Anyways enough of my whining. Could someone tell me why this regex doesn't exclude hyphens or brackets:

```
/^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z\d_]*/
```

The way I understand it (or at least what I'm trying to do), the `^` character dictates that the regex should start with the next thing on the list That means the regex should start with `[A-Za-z_]` or any character a-z and A-Z as well as and underscore `_`. Then the string can have anything that includes `[A-Za-z\d_]` which is any alphanumeric character and an underscore. Then I use the `*` to say that the string can have any number of what was presented previously (any alphanumeric character plus underscore). At no point to I specify a bracket `[` or a hyphen `-`. Why does this expression not exclude these characters

**Extra info**
I'm  verifying this with javascript:

```
function variableName(name) {
    const reg = RegExp("^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z\d_]*")
    return reg.test(name)
}

function variableName("va[riable0") // returns true should be false
```

Comment: Because your're missing the `$` anchor

Comment: just build your regex's in a regex tool like this one: https://www.regexpal.com/ makes it super easy to figure out your regexes without struggling through tutorials. not affiliated, just use it all the time.

Comment: Visualize it: [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5BA-Za-z_%5D%5BA-Za-z%5Cd_%5D*%2F)

Comment: Side note: `[A-Za-z\d_]` is represented by `\w`. You can shorten your regex to `^[A-Za-z_]\w*` or `[^\W\d]\w*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches the *part of* the string that does not contain the bracket, because your're missing the [`$` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that would (together with `^`) force it to match the whole string. Use

```
const reg = /^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z\d_]*$/g
//                                 ^
function variableName(name) {
    return reg.test(name)
}

console.log(variableName("va[riable0"))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's actually matching the first 2 letters("va"), that's why it's true.

To match the whole phrase, your reg expression should have "$" at the end:

**`"^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z\d_]*$"`**